# How to extract frames using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, compression, ffmpeg

I have a .avi file with me. How can I extract all the frames from it using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following syntax, derived [from the documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html). The %d variable will be replaced, at runtime, with a 0-based incrementing number.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi output%d.jpg
```

Comment: It works, but it copies each frame multiple times...