# How do I extract Opus frames from audio file with FFmpeg?

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg

I know that it is possible to extract video frames as pictures with FFmpeg from this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/170619/how-to-extract-frames-using-ffmpeg). I want to do the same thing with audio file. Let's say I have a file  `audio.opus`. With FFmpeg I want to extract the Opus binary frames to pipe them to my program(in following example I am testing file output). Please don't confuse binary Opus frames(packets) that I need with binary raw data. I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.opus -acodec copy frame_%d.opus <-- Just creates file "frame_%d.opus"
ffmpeg -i audio.opus -acodec copy frame_%d.bin <-- Errors with "Unable to find a suitable output format for 'frame_%d.bin'"
ffmpeg -i audio.opus -acodec copy frame_%d <-- Same error
```

I guess the problem is that there is no extention for audio frame (like `.png` or `.jpg` for video frame), so FFmpeg is confused. Is it possible to solve my problem?

Comment: There's no such thing as an audio frame. 1/24s audio would be barely distinguishable unless it was a simple wave such as a sine.

Comment: @Tetsujin As far as I get it Opus codec **is** made of frames (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)#Features <- Read first sentence from here), 2.5 to 60 ms. Yes, one frame is barely distinguishable, but I am trying to create an audio player that will play them nicely. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: A very quick read would suggest these are encapsulated data frames rather than things considered to be actually 'audio'. tbh, I never work with opus [because it serves no purpose in pro audio work, it's more of a 'network' format.. & macOS doesn't get along with it at all], though I've been a pro sound engineer for 40 years. I can't help any further, sorry. I still can't see them as being any use, sonically, as they are unlikely to start & end at zero crossings, vital if you want to chop up audio & it be even vaguely listenable afterwards.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for your time

Comment: Use the segment muxer with data as segment_format. http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, ffmpeg can't do this.

## Context

Asker is correct that opus contains something called frames. Nominally, a stream of opus frames could be used to play audio, but that would require the *decoder* of that audio to know something about the stream a-priori. That is why its non-standard. If you have an audio player that (1) has some mechanism to segment opus frames in order (for example because each frame is a separate file, and (2) knows encoding information about the frames, i.e. frame size and which stream it belongs to, then this is also possible.

### Up one level

Opus frames are normally wrapped in opus *packets*. An opus packet captures basic metadata such as the frame size, number of frames in the packet, and stereo vs mono, audio bandwidth, etc. This is still in the land of opus.

### Up another level

Normally, for both opus streams, and .opus files, the file is actually an *ogg container*. The ogg container is segmented into *pages*. An ogg file/stream has two starting pages preceeding the pages that contain opus packets. The final ogg page has an end-of-stream marker.

*If you want to stream opus-encoded using an audio player, you should probably encode and decode using ogg-opus, which is the only standard approach here.*

## Recommendation

As above, you should consider just using ogg-opus. That is the standard way to stream opus "frames" (actually inside of opus packets, inside of ogg pages, with preceeding metadata pages and an optional trailing EOS page...)

If you're trying to *rip an opus stream from another file* then you should use `oggz-rip`. This will produce an ogg-opus file containing just the one stream.

If you're sure that you want to handle and segment opus frames yourself, you'll need to write a decoder or otherwise extract data using something like `oggz-dump`. Take a look at pyogg.

*If* ffmpeg could help you here, then *maybe* you could use it as a muxer to stream the ogg-opus stream from another source, but that would still be ogg pages and not opus frames as you've originally asked for.

---

Source: I have read RFC 6716 and 7845